# Am i allowed to cache AdMob NativeAd?

Tags: admob

I want to cache one NativeAd and show it in my recyclerView. I want it to be ready on adapter creation, so that i do not have notifyDatasetChanged() called and recreate my RecyclerView holders again. 
That completely messes up UX, and i do not want that. So, i`m asking, can i send request, get NativeAd, store it in some static variable or whatever from Activity1 and then show it in RecyclerView in Activity2?
Would Admob cut my revenue? Would Google sanction my app or worse, my account? 
What will happen if i do that?